# What should be the approach to delete a static pointer to own class?

Tags: c++, static, delete-operator

How should we delete a static pointer of a class which is pointing to itself ? How to write destructor for this?

PS: I am just trying this out of curiosity.

```
#include <iostream>
class rest
{
    static rest *own;

public:
    int x;
    rest(int x) : x(x)
    {
        std::cout << "creating rest object";
    }
    ~rest()
    {
        std::cout << "destructor";
    }
    static void set(rest *setOwn)
    {
        own = setOwn;
    }
};
rest *rest::own = NULL;

int main()
{
    rest *x = new rest(1);
    rest *y = new rest(2);
    rest::set(y);
    delete x  // Consider there will be only one object x and as soon as x gets deleted, I want to delete static class object(own) as well.
```

Comment: It isn't clear under what condition you want to destroy the object pointed by `own`. What happens if you add a `rest *z = new rest(3);`. Do you want to destroy `y` when you `delete x;`? What about `z`?

Comment: Note that your code is incorrect. Despite doing `x->own=y`, since `own` is a static variable, it is not owned by `x`. Your code is equivalent to do `rest::own = y`, where it is clear that it does not belong to `x`

Comment: `delete rest::own` or `delete y`? It sounds like you're trying to do something like a `std::unique_ptr` potentially.

Comment: `delete y;`  or `delete rest::own;` does the same. You could make `own` a `unique_ptr<rest>` instead to get it automatically `delete`d

Comment: Please explain your problem here. You can still `delete rest::own;` later, but then if you also do `delete y;` that's a double delete. Also, As LoPiTaL mentioned, you should rather use `rest::own = y;`

Comment: Few edits, all I want is that I have one object and a class object and I want to delete my class object  as soon as my object is deleted.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ singleton scott meyers thread safe".

Comment: (Not your problem) C++ provides "nullptr".

Answer (score 3):

When you write code in C++ you have to think about lifetime.  That decision is **up to you**, as a programmer.

By far the easiest way to think about lifetime is to phrase it in terms of ownership; blocks of code (or objects) "own" the lifetime of resources.  When the block of code ends, of the object is destroyed, it frees the resource.

That resource can, in turn, be an object that could free further resources.

This is not the only way to think about ownership.

In your case, because `own` is a static variable, there is no clear owner.

So you have more work to do.

Your responsibility is to ensure that the resource that `own` points to is cleaned up after nobody else needs it (the dangling pointer problem, but before you lose track of it (the leak problem).

If you rewrite your code in terms of RAII and the Rule of 5/0, then this becomes easy.  If you don't, then you have to prove your code correct using a bunch of work.

You can have programs where the resource ownership problem is a Turing complete one that you have proved to yourself does not result in dangling pointers or leaks.  And in theory the problem you are trying to solve could be so hard you have no choice but to make an insane resource lifetime system like that.

I don't know your real problem, so I cannot tell you how you should solve your resource lifetime issue.

But 99% of the time, you should rewrite your code to be RAII and rule of 5/0 friendly.